# Erratic behavior of executeScript: "Cannot access a chrome:// URL" on http://www.imdb.com/list

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm executing content scripts on some http://www.imdb.com/list... specific urls.
It works fine most of the time, but sometimes it's not.  Then I reload the page with F5, and again, it works well most of the time.
In an event page I listen for onDOMContentLoaded

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(listener, {'url': urlFilter});
```

The listener hangs well.

```
function listener(tab){
    t=tab;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'elementoWeb 2.1.js'}, function(resultado){
        if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
            console.log('Ejecutando elementoWeb.js, chrome.runtime.lasterror: ', chrome.runtime.lastError, '\nTab: ', t);
    }); 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'imdbListaCs.js'}    , function(resultado){
        if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
            console.log('Ejecutando imdbListaCs.js, chrome.runtime.lasterror: ', chrome.runtime.lastError, '\nTab: ', t);
    });
}
```

When it fails, there are two console's logs like this, one for each execution attempt:

```
Ejecutando elementoWeb.js, chrome.runtime.lasterror:  Object {message: "Cannot access a chrome:// URL"} 
Tab:  Object {frameId: 0, processId: 320, tabId: 405, timeStamp: 1421159075402.253, url: "http://www.imdb.com/list/......"}
frameId: 0
processId: 320
tabId: 405
timeStamp: 1421159075402.253
url: "http://www.imdb.com/list/......"
__proto__: Object
```

(I shortened imdb's urls)

Tab 405 is the one with the imdb.com page on it.  Not a chrome://url.

Sometimes the error messages differs:

```
Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?&dockSide=undocked&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

I don't have any devtools' experiments activated.

Anyone with the same odd problem?

Comment: What's the `urlFilter`?

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in background page's console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded` event does not get a [`Tab` object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab), but an object that contains information about the navigation. Take a look at the [documentation of the event listener's callback function](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-onDOMContentLoaded-callback) (or look at the object that you printed to the console!), it shows that the ID of the tab is provided in the `tabId` property.

In your code, you read a non-existent property of the parameter (hence `undefined`) and pass it to [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). Because the tab ID is missing, `executeScript` defaults to the active tab of the current window. When the navigation is triggered while you're at a different window or tab, the content script is inserted in the wrong tab. If you don't have access to that tab (e.g. because it's `chrome://newtab`), Chrome refuses to execute the script. If you're viewing a devtools window, then you'll get an error about that window (though not any more [starting Chrome 41](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=427226#c10)).

To fix your problem, change your function to

```
function listener(details) { // changed "tab" to "details"
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, // (was "tab.id")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I don't know why it worked even with that mistake, but now I don't care.  Actually, applying your suggestion the problem continued, but this time I could detect that listener is sometimes called with a null argument, I don't know why, and that causes the error.  Now I check it from the beginning.